# Display 240 Pictures, 9 per Page in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have the code bellow:

```
SELECT *,
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY person_id) -1 )/3 AS RowGrpNo,
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY person_id) -1 )%3 AS ColGrpNo,
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY person_id)-1)/9 AS PageGrpNo
FROM
(

SELECT DISTINCT
  People.person_id,
  People.ActivePassive,
  PeoplePicture.person_id,
  PeoplePicture.picture_id,
  PeoplePicture.Picture
  FROM People
  Right Join PeoplePicture
  On People.person_id = PeoplePicture.person_id
  WHERE People.ActivePassive = 'Active'
)t​
```

In addition I have 240 images. I want to display them in SSRS (9 images per page). But I only get the first three as shown below:

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjOia.png)

How do I make the remaining 6 pictures visible, they where suppose to be where there are boxes in red. Please help.

Bellow is the report in report builder 3.0:

[image: Report]

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in SSRS, not your your SQL (not that we can run your SQL either without sample data). You might want to include details of your report here.

Comment: Yeah I don't see any problem with the SQL.   The problem must be in the report, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I have just edited the report in report builder above

Comment: are you getting 3 images on every page? make sure your placeholder can grow vertically

Comment: it is only three images on first page, and no second page, it is so strange.

Comment: I noticed your query shows `person_id` in the page group no. Is that a typo? The first two are `person_id_id`...

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I edited it, but this typo was only on stackoverflow, not on the report.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by doing the following:

Modify your inner select to include a `rownumber` column. This is simply to number your rows from 1 through to how many ever is returned in your dataset.

On your outer select, add another column (lets call it `row_display`).. set this to be `rownumber % 3` -- since you want 3 images per line.

Now in your report designer, place 3 `tablix` of the same dimensions side by side  to hold the photos

Lets call them `tablix1`, `tablix2` and `tablix3`

they all display the same data.. except, each tablix has a different set of filters.

On `tablix1`, add a filter and `set row_display = 1`

On `tablix2`, add a filter and `set row_display = 2`

On `tablix3`, add a filter and `set row_display = 0`

You may need to adjust the size of the tablix depending on how many images are returned per page..

Preview the report and watch the magic happen.. hopefully.

Additionally. if you did another rownumber and call it pagebreak.. set this pagebreak column to increment by 1 every 9 rows .. you can then group all the tablix by the pagebreak column add a pagebreak between each instance of the group.. you would get 3 images across and 9 lines of images..